How close to the nucleous do electrons have to come before magnetic force dominates?
Sorry for an unusually complex question.  The answer to a previous question At what distance does magnetic attraction between two properly aligned electrons overcome electric repulsion? suggests that with two properly aligned free electrons magnetism would overcome it's electric repulsion at about 190 fm but it would likely take great energy for two electrons to bond like this unless electric chrage was neutralized by proximity to an oppositely charged nucleous.  On the other hand inside a neutral atom we see electrons pair up and this is basis for chemical bonding.  It seems likely this is a magnetic attraction between them.  In any event is it possible to calculate how close a pair of electrons would have to come to the neucleous before they attract magneticly?

@my2cts I am the author of both and referenced the other question in this one.  I am indeed sure they are different.  One question is about free electrons where their repulsion and at full whereas the other is about electrons which electric repulsion is canceled by being within an atom.  Do you see how they are different now?

It does not matter. It is the same distance.

@my2cts I am unsure why?  Electric field is neutralized within an atom is it not?  Seems like the distance would be much larger!

The kinetic energy goes through the roof at a distance of 190 fm, which is 300 times smaller than a Bohr radius. This is what prevents the electron from falling onto the proton, as classical mechanics predicts.

What on earth could neutralize, I assume that you mean screen, the electron charge? Especially at a distance of 190 fm?

You should study the Schrödinger equation for hydrogen a little more.

What is the difference between neutralizing and screening a charge?
